# Find appropriate AWS policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iam

I have created a user group in AWS ("developers"). Now I want to attach a policy to the group which will grant the users permission to list, create and update Amplify apps. I am struggling to determine the appropriate policy.

I see that the "AdministratorAccess" policy includes access to the *AWS Amplify* service, but I don't want the developers to have administrator level access. What are my options?

Edit:
When the specific user accesses the Amplify console the following error is displayed

```
List apps call failed User: arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXX:user/myUser is not authorized to perform: amplify:ListApps on resource: arn:aws:amplify:eu-west-1:XXXXXXXXXX:apps/*
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create your own IAM policy, you can use the visual editor present in IAM. Using visual editor, you can construct a new policy from scratch using the very intuitive GUI.

Goto **IAM**, then **policies**, then use **visual editor**.

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: The question asks how to restrict access for developers. Visual editor provides you a GUI for creating custom policies.

Answer (score 0):

I had to log in as root user, then access the IAM service.

Under policies click "Create Policy", then select "Amplify" under the Select a service.

Answer (score -1):

This link detail how we can create role for providing access to applications in aws and you can grant these role to your group .

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2.html

Another way you can create your own policy and assign to group .

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_create.html

Comment: Thanks, but just to clarify. I want to grant access to users (via a group), not EC2 instances. The other part of the question is how do I determine the appropriate policy to assign fromthe existing AWS policies.